Flutter How to emit stream event at the same time every day
I am using a Stream to check the current time against a stored DateTime value. I only need this stream to emit a value once per day at the same time, say 00.01. How can I set up my Stream to emit an event at this time every single day? Some method of creating an initial value of 00.01 and then setting Duration to 1 day seems logical but I cannot get the Stream to initialise with the value and then wait 1 day to emit the next event.
Stream<DateTime> currentTime() async* {
    yield* Stream.periodic(Duration(seconds: 100), (_) => DateTime.now());
  }


Are you also considering running in background or just in app?

I have a series of other data streams that all depend on this DateTime stream, to update their values according to the streamed date (day). Currently this DateTime stream emits an event every hour which means all other streams refresh and update too often. I require some logic to emit that event only once per day and struggle with a consistent solution. Any recommendation greatly appreciated, thanks

DateTimeStream.broadCast  and add subscription when needed this is what I can get from this. Also I might prefer creating a repo with DateTimeStream (along with those dependencies) and update within the repo
